# DateFormat discrepancy

Tags: java, date, date-format

We're trying to format dates according to the browser locale.
However, we're getting a different output when we pass "en_GB" to initialize a `Locale` reference and pass it to a `DateFormat`, as against using the "pure" `Locale` reference from the `request`.

In the former case, the output is: 6/20/13, while in the latter the (correct) output is: 20/06/13.

What could the reason for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_GB");
```

You should be using:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB");
```

To specify language and country, you use separate arguments. Likewise if you want to include a variant, you use the constructor with three parameters.

Comment: Yes, someone told me exactly that as soon as I posted the question -- I kind of feel dumb now.:). Thanks anyways!